# XCode 11: Background region monitoring does not work

Tags: xcode, background, geolocation

After hours of reading and re-coding I still can't find a solution.

I want to build a simple app, that tracks my location in the background. On first application load I set up a region around my current location, start monitoring for exactly this region and stopUpdatingLocations. Once the app gets the didExitRegion event, I again get the current location, set up another region (after cleaning all other monitored regions) and it all starts again.

The app has alwaysAuthorization for location, background mode for location updates is set, PList contains LocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription and LocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.

For some time, it works great. But after many hours of not moving, the app gets suspended and does not receive any more location updates, not even the monitor event, which should relaunch the app when I understand this () correctly.

Could anyboy give me a hint?

Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    let currentNotifications = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()


    currentNotifications.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in }
        }
    }


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    return true
}

}

extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


    let location = locations[0]


    let now = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()


    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"


    for region in locationManager.monitoredRegions {
        locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
    }


    var regionIdentifier = String(format: "%f", location.coordinate.latitude) + ", " + String(format: "%f", location.coordinate.latitude) + "( set on " + formatter.string(from: now) + ")"


    var geofenceRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude), radius: 250, identifier: regionIdentifier)


    geofenceRegion.notifyOnExit = true
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: geofenceRegion)


    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


}




func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
    sendNotification(title: "Event triggered", subtitle: "Region exit", body: region.identifier)
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


}

public func sendNotification(title: String, subtitle: String, body: String) {


let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = title
content.subtitle = subtitle
content.body = body
content.sound = .default


let identifier = "geoStalker4_notification_" + String(format: "%f", NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)


let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false)


let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: nil)


UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your locationManager settings:

```
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```